# Qt app bundle for MacOS is too slow

Tags: macos, qt

I build my Qt application on Mac (Mavericks), using CMake. It creates a bundle file in the build directory called SquiggleMark.app.

Next I run a script that copies libraries into the bundle, just Qt framework and libqcocoa.dylib files.

Finally I use iDMG to create a dmg file.

Now if I mount this dmg file and run my app from the mount, it runs fine. But if I move the dmg to /Applications and run it from Finder > Applications, it takes very long time, couple of minutes to launch.

**How can I debug this?**

I suspect it is taking too long to find the libraries in Finder, but I am not sure.

When I run the app from terminal, by typing "/Applications/SquiggleMark/Contents/MacOS/SquiggleMark", it also works fine.

[The dmg is here](http://www.osletek.com/squigglemark/downloads/SquiggleMark.dmg) You can try it out and tell me if you are seeing the same long load time as I am.

My bundling script has commands like this:

install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets  $BUNDLE/Contents/Frameworks/QtWidgets

install_name_tool -change $QTDIR/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets $BUNDLE/Contents/MacOS/$APP

I am not posting the whole script because it is too long, however if someone wants it, I can put it up here.

Comment: Newer versions of MacOS/X will do a security scan of the application the first time it is executed, and that can take a little while to complete.  Perhaps you are seeing that?  If so, launching should be much faster the second time you run it.

Comment: That does not seem to be the case, it is always slow from Finder and always fast from terminal

Comment: Have you considered using macdeployqt? Open terminal and run this: `<QtDir>/<QtVersion>/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt yourapp.app/ -verbose=2 -dmg`. I believe this will only work on release versions and not debug.

Comment: Dunno what's going on, then, but as far as debugging it... I'd do a fopen("/tmp/hey_rosewater.txt", "w"); at the top of main(), and then do ffprintf's (followed by fflush()'s) into that file at various points during the program's execution.    The data written via fprintf() should include the current timestamp, so that when you look at the file afterwards you can see how much time elapsed between each fprintf() call.  That would at least tell you whether the delay is occurring before main() or somehow during main(), and if the latter, you could narrow down where.

Comment: Is "open SquiggleMark.app" from the CLI also slow?